# How do I configure what fonts are used for Japanese characters?

Tags: java, fonts, japanese

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do fonts work in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107516/how-do-fonts-work-in-ubuntu)

I would like to know how I can control which fonts are used for rendering Japanese characters.

Also, I would like to know if there is anything special I need to do to control what fonts are used for Japanese characters in Java applications.

Thanks!